# VS2008 SP1 hot-fixes for C++ development: where can I found a comprehensive list?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I'm still using VS2008 SP1 for C++ development mainly because the IDE is faster than VS2010 SP1.

I'd like to have a comprehensive list of post-SP1 hot-fixes for VS2008, focused on C++ development.

I found some of them in this blog post: **[Available hotfixes for VC2005-SP1 / VC2008 RTM / VC2008-SP1](http://blog.kalmbach-software.de/2008/04/30/available-hotfixes-for-vc2005-sp1-vc2008-rtm/)** .

However, this list seems not comprehensive. For example, I happened to find this blog post by Visual C++ Team: **[Visual C++ Precompiled Header Errors on Windows 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/11/12/visual-c-precompiled-header-errors-on-windows-7.aspx)**, which contains a link to another post-SP1 hot-fix for VS2008: [KB976656](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=25785)

Comment: @ildjarn: it seems your link answers my question. Thanks. The list comprehends also non-C++ related stuff, and it seems that there is no good filtering capability on that web page (e.g. filter only C++ hot-fixes, filter only stuff for VS2008, etc.); but better than nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page is the only one I'm aware of that resembles anything comprehensive:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/downloads/